# What's the difference between FindAll and Select?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I used `List.Select(condition).Count()` and found the result to be inappropriate and then I tried `List.FindAll(condition).Count()` and it worked fine.

How does List.Select(condition).count work ?

Comment: how did you specify condition in `List.Select`, you need `List.Where`

Comment: List.select(mylist => mylist.key == "somevalue").count()

Comment: @DotnayTupperson Did have you tried your code before posting?

Comment: @Bedford - That's not at all the same question.

Comment: Seems like you misunderstand what `Select` does....

Comment: From MSDN: `A query expression must terminate with either a select clause or a group clause.` Not to mention, `Where` is what you need, not `Select`, as Habib mentioned :)

Comment: `Select` means "select a value (derived) *from each* Item" (it is a transformation operation over the individual values) and *not* "choose particular items from a sequence". The LINQ counterpart to FindAll is `Where`.

Answer (score 6):

You see different results because

```
list.Select(condition)
```

transforms the list into a sequence of `True` and `False` values with the length that is always equal to the number of items in the `list`. If you use `Where` instead of `Select`, you will get matching results.

However, a shorter way to get the result is to pass the condition to `Count`, like this:

```
var res = list.Count(condition);
```

Answer (score 3):

`List.Select` Invokes a transform function on each element in the sequence and returns the transformed collection. In general, using this will return the same `Count` as the original collection.

`List.FindAll` takes a predicate (similar to `List.Where`) and so will only return elements matching it, giving a different count from the original.

Answer (score 2):

Your code or way to filter out list is fundamentally wrong. What you are trying to do is:

```
 list.Select(mylist => mylist.key == "somevalue").Count();
```

This will return the same count as length of List. The resulting collection will be true/false for each item.

You need `Enumerable.Where` like:

```
 list.Select(mylist => mylist.key == "somevalue").Count();
```

This will give you the same count as you are finding in `FindAll` method.

You can even pass the predicate to Count like:

```
var count = list.Count(mylist => mylist.Key == "somevalue");
```

`FindAll` is different from `Enumerable.Where` in a way that `FindAll` constructs a new list, whereas `Enumerable.Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. You can read this question for more info: [C# FindAll VS Where Speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260220/c-sharp-findall-vs-where-speed)

Answer (score 1):

Using `Select` performs a *mapping* operation, not a filter operation.  This means you'll always get the same number of items out of the query as you had in the original list.  In your case, you projected the list from a `List<T>` to an `IEnumerable<bool>` (with the original number of true or false responses).

Use `.Where` to filter a list.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
List.select(mylist => mylist.key == "somevalue")
```

creates a list of values "true" and "false" but does not filter the output. Therefore the count is the same as without select.

```
List.select(mylist => mylist.key == "somevalue").count()
```

is the same as

```
List.count();
```

And

```
List.where(mylist => mylist.key == "somevalue").count()
```

works the way you want.