# Find list of item properties

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have Class as defined below

```
class Employee
{
    public int EmpNo{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Designation{get;set;}
}
```

and I have a list of employees

```
List<Employee>
```

I can find a list of employees with similar designation, using FindAll() method.

But I want to have a list(or array) of EmpNo and not list of Employees. I can use a for loop to construct, but want a different answer using predicate. How can I do it? or is it not possible? I think had got a solution for similar problem earlier, but not getting it now.

May be Something like FindAll(...).ToArray().

---

EDIT

Ok I got the answer.

```
FindAll(emp => emp.Designation.Equals("Executive")).Select(item => item.EmpNo).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative is;

```
employees
.Where(emp => emp.Designation.Equals("Executive"))
.Select(item => item.EmpNo).ToList()
```

There are slight performance differences between FindAll and Where, have a look at this;

[FindAll vs Where extension-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531702/findall-vs-where-extension-method)