# Find a char in a List of Strings

Tags: c#, list

I'm looking for a smart way to find List-Elements with a specific Character in a List of Strings.

I want to find all Strings, wich contains a ?-sign in a List of Strings like:
"a?11", "ab12", "bb12", "b?13"

My current solution looks like this:

```
// Interates through all strings.
foreach (string currentString in listOfStrings)
{
  if (currentString.Contains('?'))
  {
    // Found!
    myStrings.Add(currentString);
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this job, maybe like:

```
List<string> myStrings = listOfStrings.Select(z => z.Contains('?')).ToList();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: better is extremely relative.  I'd try codereview.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
listOfStrings.Where(s => s.Contains('?'));
```

Comment: Simple as it is. :)
I tryed FindAll instead of Where and it works too.
Are there any differences?
Thank you very much!

Comment: @ChristophBrückmann There's a good explanation of the differences here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531702/findall-vs-where-extension-method