# Find multiple element and set an attribute depending on the result

Tags: c#, linq, set

Him

I have a `List<MyObject> _users`, and I would like to find all users which the userName begin by "toto" and set an attribute, for all of them, **bool excepted = true**.

I actually have this code:

```
_users.FindAll(z => z.userName.StartWith("toto") == true && location == "London")
```

and I would like to reach something like this:

```
_users.FindAll(z => z.userName.StartWith("toto") == true && location == "London").Cast<MyObject>().excepted = true;
```

The Cast to know which kind of object that I'm currently using, and then set my attribute.... This code obviously don't work at all, but I have no idea how could I do it and if it possible to do that :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
_users.FindAll(z => z.userName.StartWith("toto") == true && location == "London")
      .ForEach(x=>x.excepted =true)
```

Comment: You gave me an orgasm ! ahah thank you so much ! :D I need more practice on these kind of queries :)

Answer (score 1):

```
_users.Where(x => x.userName.Contains("toto")).ToList().ForEach(y => y.excepted = true);
```

Comment: What is the best optimization between these results ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531702/findall-vs-where-extension-method, I found a cool topic about the optimization :)

Comment: Answer is valid but it won't optimize the code in anyway..`ToList` would create a `List<T>` and so is exactly similar to `FindAll`..To really optimize it use foreach loop over `_users.Where` without using `ToList`(though it won't make any significant difference)